# How can I make some hierarchy when interacting with objects(items)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the interactable item script that I'm attaching to object I want to be interactable :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System;

public class InteractableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum InteractableMode
    {
        Description,
        Action,
        ActionWithoutThrow
    };

    public InteractableMode interactableMode = InteractableMode.Description;
    public float distance;

    [TextArea(1, 10)]
    public string description = "";

    public bool IsAnyAction()
    {
        return interactableMode == InteractableMode.ActionWithoutThrow || interactableMode == InteractableMode.Action;
    }
}
```

This script is using the InteractableItem script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class IKControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<InteractableItem> lookObj = new List<InteractableItem>();
    public GameObject objToThrow;
    public Text text;
    public float weightDamping = 1.5f;
    public bool RightHandToTarget = true;
    public float throwSpeed;
    public bool handFinishedMove = false;

    private List<InteractableItem> allDetectedItems;
    private Animator animator;
    private InteractableItem lastPrimaryTarget;
    private float lerpEndDistance = 0.1f;
    private float finalLookWeight = 0;
    private bool transitionToNextTarget = false;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        allDetectedItems = new List<InteractableItem>();
    }

    // Callback for calculating IK
    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {
        if (lookObj != null)
        {
            lookObj.RemoveAll(x => x == null);

            InteractableItem primaryTarget = null;
            
            float closestLookWeight = 0;

            // Here we find the target which is closest (by angle) to the players view line
            allDetectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (InteractableItem target in lookObj)
            {
                Vector3 lookAt = target.transform.position - transform.position;
                lookAt.y = 0f;

                // Filter out all objects that are too far away
                if (lookAt.magnitude > target.distance) continue;

                float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 0f, transform.forward.z).normalized, lookAt.normalized);
                float lookWeight = Mathf.Clamp(dotProduct, 0f, 1f);
                if (lookWeight > 0.1f && lookWeight > closestLookWeight)
                {
                    closestLookWeight = lookWeight;
                    primaryTarget = target;
                    allDetectedItems.Add(target);
                }
            }

            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                if ((lastPrimaryTarget != null) && (lastPrimaryTarget != primaryTarget) && (finalLookWeight > 0f))
                {
                    // Here we start a new transition because the player looks already to a target but
                    // we have found another target the player should look at
                    transitionToNextTarget = true;
                }
            }

            // The player is in a neutral look position but has found a new target
            if ((primaryTarget != null) && !transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                if(primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.ActionWithoutThrow)
                {
                    RightHandToTarget = true;
                }

                lastPrimaryTarget = primaryTarget;
                //finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, closestLookWeight, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 1f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(primaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget && primaryTarget.IsAnyAction())
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = primaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 1f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, primaryTarget.transform.position);

                    // -> new code block
                    if (finalLookWeight > 0.95f) // here you can play with a value between 0.95f -> 1.0f
                    {
                        

                        if(primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action)
                        // call your funtion to shoot something here
                        StartCoroutine(ThrowObject(objToThrow.transform, primaryTarget.transform.position, 30f));
                    }

                    if(finalLookWeight > 0.9f)
                    {
                        handFinishedMove = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Let the player smoothly look away from the last target to the neutral look position
            if ((primaryTarget == null && lastPrimaryTarget != null) || transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 0f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 0.5f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);
                }

                if (finalLookWeight < lerpEndDistance)
                {
                    transitionToNextTarget = false;
                    finalLookWeight = 0f;
                    lastPrimaryTarget = null;
                }
            }

            // Show primary object found by the player
            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                text.text = primaryTarget.description;
            }
            else
            {
                text.text = "";
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ThrowObject(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 currentPos = objectToMove.position;

            float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;

            objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, toPosition, time);

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I have two objects(items) in the game that are very close to each other, the distance between them for example is 1 or less then 1. Then the IKControl will work with the first interactable item but will never work with the second near interactable item.

For example if there are two cubes and the distance between them is 1 or less then 1 or even if the distance between them is 100, which one to interact first ? Andi f the List lookObj contains 20 items and I want first to interact with item 15 then 1 then 5 then 19 ?

How can I set the order of the interactable with the items ?

I thought to use reorderablelist somehow but not sure if this is the solution and how to do it.

For now I did something ugly that work but ugly :
I destroyed the script from one item and added to another item to create some order :

```
Destroy(securityKeyPad.GetComponent<InteractableItem>());
            StartCoroutine(DestroyKeyPad1());
            var naviInteractable = navi.AddComponent<InteractableItem>();
            naviInteractable.distance = 0.5f;
            navi.GetComponent<InteractableItem>().interactableMode = InteractableItem.InteractableMode.ActionWithoutThrow;
```

But the second item is not yet added to the lookObj yet so this is another problem.

I thought to make some editor script/s that if I attach to an object the InteractableItem script it will automatic add it to the lookObj List in the IKControl script in the editor before running the game !

And then in the lookObj List to be able to control the items interactable order, that's why I thought also to use a reorderablelist instead just using the List.

I'm a bit stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to choose a specific target based on some kind of criteria, such as the "lookWeight" you're calculating in the foreach loop. I'd suggest creating an extra "lookWeight" field in InteractableItem:

```
public class InteractableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    //...
    public float lookWeight;
}
```

Then you can just save this "lookWeight" in the foreach loop and then sort/order it after the loop finishes. Include the Linq namespace to support ordering:

```
using System.Linq;

foreach (InteractableItem target in lookObj)
{
    //...
    target.lookWeight = lookWeight;
    allDetectedItems.Add(target);
}

// put into ascending order by look weight and set target to first item
if (allDetectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    allDetectedItems = allDetectedItems.OrderBy(x => x.lookWeight).ToList();
    primaryTarget = allDetectedItems.First();
}

if (primaryTarget != null)
//...
```

If you want to order on something else, instead of "lookWeight", just add it to the InteractableItem class instead.